# Zip4j: Name mismatch for splits

Tags: java, zip, zip4j

after calling 
***createZipFileFromFolder(source, parameters, true, splitSize)***
the generated file name mismatch the physical name **BUT** only for the splited file number 10. So the name generated by the function ***getSplitZipFiles()*** will be 'filename.z010' while the real file name store is  'filename.z10'.

any idea why? and how to fix it

```
 File outFile = new File(out_zip);
```

ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(out_zip);
ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
zipFile.createZipFileFromFolder(source, parameters, true, splitSize);
splitZipFiles = zipFile.getSplitZipFiles();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug in 'zip4j'.

It's because of this logic in 'Zip4jUtil' class. For file number 9, the if condition fails, but fileExt is still '.z0' and adds +1 to the file name. Instead the condition should have been if(i>=9) to match the file creation logic.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfThisDisk; i++) {
                if (i == numberOfThisDisk) {
                    retList.add(zipModel.getZipFile());
                } else {
                    String fileExt = ".z0";
                    if (i > 9) {
                        fileExt = ".z";
                    }
                    partFile = (zipFileName.indexOf(".") >= 0) ? currZipFile.substring(0, currZipFile.lastIndexOf(".")) : currZipFile;
                    partFile = partFile + fileExt + (i + 1);
                    retList.add(partFile);
                }
            }
```

But while creating the actual split file in 'SplitOutputStream' class, the logic is fine to generate the proper file name. Below code will generate '.z10' file instead of '.z010'.

```
if (currSplitFileCounter < 9) {
            currSplitFile = new File(parentPath + zipFileWithoutExt + ".z0" + (currSplitFileCounter + 1));
        } else {
            currSplitFile = new File(parentPath + zipFileWithoutExt + ".z" + (currSplitFileCounter + 1));
        }
```

So file creation is fine, the problem is with the logic while listing the files.

### Solution:

1) Submit the bug report to the dev team, and meanwhile grab the source of '`zip4j`' from `http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php`.

2) Then change the logic `if(i>9) to if(i>=9)` in '`Zip4jUtil.java`' @ line: 690. Create the binary .jar file and use it in your application.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.. as a solution I add this       if(splitZipFiles.size()>=10) splitZipFiles.set(9, splitZipFiles.get(9).toString().replaceFirst(".z010",".z10")) ;